# Flutter : Execution failed for task ':geolocator:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, location-provider, geolocator

This project build perfectly before January of this Year. But now it's show me error. First They show me location 16+ error. Then I changed the location package to geolocator. but not fixed.
Then create new project and import old code base.
and also change target and compilesdk to 31. and uncomment `compileOptions`

**Here is my app level build.gradle-**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    // compileOptions {
    //     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    //     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    // }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "care.appnameexample.health"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.6'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Here is my `pubspec.yaml` file -**

```
name: appnameexample
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"  // Environment changed after transfer to new project

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.3
  animations: ^1.1.2
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
  flutter_signin_button: ^1.1.0
  http: ^0.12.2
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4
  intl: ^0.17.0
  chips_choice: ^1.4.1
  rflutter_alert: ^1.1.0
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  fluid_bottom_nav_bar: ^1.1.1
  dropdown_formfield: ^0.1.3
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12
  share: ^0.6.5+3
  autocomplete_textfield: ^1.7.3
  otp_text_field: ^1.0.1
  firebase_database: ^4.0.0
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  audioplayers: ^0.16.1

  agora_rtc_engine: ^3.3.1
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1
  audio_manager: ^0.5.5+3

  after_layout: ^1.0.7+2
  geocoder: ^0.2.1
  geolocator:
  webview_flutter: ^1.0.5
  location_web: ^1.0.0

  image_picker: ^0.6.7+11
  dio: ^3.0.10
  path_provider: ^1.6.18

  path:
  sizer: ^1.1.8

  # For Calender
  calendar_timeline: ^0.7.1
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.6

#  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.11
  maps_launcher: ^2.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  flutter_email_sender: ^5.0.0
  pin_code_fields: ^7.0.0

  firebase_messaging:
  flutter_local_notifications: ^3.0.1+7

  flutter_inappwebview: ^4.0.0+4
  flutter_downloader: ^1.5.2

  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.1
  expand_widget: ^2.1.0
  flutter_html: any
  launch_review: ^3.0.1
  package_info: ^2.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.8.1"
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
flutter_icons:
  image_path: "icon/icon.png"
  android: true
  ios: true
# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/insurance/enbn/
    - assets/images/dochome/english/
    - assets/images/dochome/bangla/
    - assets/images/patienthome/english/
    - assets/images/patienthome/bangla/
    - assets/images/pharmacyhome/english/
    - assets/images/pharmacyhome/bangla/
    - assets/images/providerhome/english/
    - assets/images/providerhome/bangla/
    - assets/images/providerservices/
    - assets/images/auth/bangla/
    - assets/images/auth/english/
    - assets/images/mdmt/
    - assets/images/newicons/
    - assets/ringtone.mp3
    - assets/calling.mp3
    - i18n/en.json
    - i18n/bn.json
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Century Gothic
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Century-Gothic.ttf
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

But Nothing is worked.
**Still now It's show me this error :**

```
ABIR appnameexample %flutter run  
Running "flutter pub get" in appnameexample...                            3.0s
The plugin `geocoder` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android
V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated
APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding:
https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Launching lib/main.dart on M2010J19SI in debug mode...
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.0.2/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audio_manager-0.5.7+1/android/src/main/java/cc/dync/audio_manager/AudioManagerPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.0.2/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.5.3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.0.2/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers-0.16.2/android/src/main/java/xyz/luan/audioplayers/AudioplayersPlugin.java:18: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar;
                                              ^
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.0.2/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers-0.16.2/android/src/main/java/xyz/luan/audioplayers/AudioplayersPlugin.java:26: warning: [deprecation] Handler() in Handler has been deprecated
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
                                    ^
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.0.2/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers-0.16.2/android/src/main/java/xyz/luan/audioplayers/AudioplayersPlugin.java:31: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
    public static void registerWith(final Registrar registrar) {
                                          ^
3 warnings
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.0.2/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-3.0.3/android/src/main/java/com/dexterous/flutterlocalnotifications/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.0.2/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geocoder-0.2.1/android/src/main/java/com/aloisdeniel/geocoder/GeocoderPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.0.2/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-6.2.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/LocationManagerClient.java:10: warning: [deprecation] LocationProvider in android.location has been deprecated
import android.location.LocationProvider;
                       ^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.0.2/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-6.2.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/LocationMapper.java:29: warning: [deprecation] isFromMockProvider() in Location has been deprecated
      position.put("is_mocked", location.isFromMockProvider());
                                        ^
1 error
2 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':geolocator:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 56s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             57.6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
ABIR appnameexample %
```

***How Can I fixed this. Please someone help me to fixed this.***

Comment: Please provide a content from your `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: @SergeyLobanov I edit my question and add 'pubspec.yaml' file

Comment: did you fix this issue, i am having same thing ,tried update like tagetsdk,compiledsdk to latest and also tried downgraded version still have same issue also tried update plugins still nothing

Comment: @Abhijith When I remove this package it's work fine

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this error? I have tried updating the targetSdk and the compileSdk and even tried downgrading the geolocator version but not working.

Comment: datetime_picker_formfield: ^2.0.1 this package is debricated, and also not null safety, try to use other library

Answer (score 6):

@abir-ashan in my case such issue like this was fixed with upgrading 'geolocator' from 6.2.1 to newer version

```
% flutter pub outdated
% flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and tried many solution, but finally the issue was solved by doing the following changes in

> android > app > src > build.gradle

```
    android {
       compileSdkVersion 31

       defaultConfig {
          minSdkVersion 21
          targetSdkVersion 29
       }
    }
```